# Domain changes required for SSL integration

Tags: dns, subdomain, https, payment-gateway

Currently my site supports regular payment options (User is taken to Payment Gateway/PG website). Now I'm trying to implement "seamless" PG integration. I need SSL for this. I'm having a dedicated server with 5 static IPs from Hostgator/HG.

options:

1. I take SSL for `www.my_domain.com`. According to HG, I need to change IP of main site as current IP is not really dedicated as it is being shared by cpanel etc. So They need to bind another dedicated IP to main domain for SSL to work. This would required DNS change for main website and hence cause few hours downtime (which is ok).
2. I've noticed that most of the e-commerce websites are using subdomains like `secure.my_domain.com` for ssl/https. This sounds like a better approach. But I've got few doubts in this case:

a) Would I need to re-register with existing PGs (Paypal, Google Checkout, Authorize.net) if I switch to subdomain? Re-registering  is not an option for me.

b) Would DNS change be required for `www.my_domain.com` in this case. This confusion arose because of following reply from HG : "If the sub domain `secure.my_domain.com` is added to an existing cPanel it will use the IP for that cPanel so as long as it is a Dedicated IP that will be fine.  If `secure.my_domain.com` gets setup as its own cPanel it will need to be assigned to a Dedicated IP which would have a DNS change involved.".

Please suggest?

Comment: would Serverfault be better place for this?

Comment: It's borderline. I don't think serverfault would cover payment gateways, whereas we do, so I'm happy for it to stay here.

Comment: Do we get answers on this forum?

Comment: Yes, only 729 out of 10,000 questions haven't been given an upvoted answer. Often it takes more than 24 hours though. If you don't get an answer after a week I suggest you delete the question here and re-ask it on serverfault.com. (We don't like the same question on two sites.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) No you definitely don't have to re-register with another PGs.  But you might have to configure your PGs to recon your new URL.  Ex: Paypal IPN requires you to give a URL so they can send payment info back to you. You might have to change that IF you want paypal to call a Secure URL.  Otherwise, you don't have to change anything. Another Ex: is authorize.net recognizes payment page URL, so you have to login to your authorize.net account to update the URL setting. (i am not sure if that's still the case, I haven't use authorize.net for a long time).

b) I never use HG, but basically you just need to add secure.yourdomain.com to your account and ask support staff to assign a static IP to it.  Then your SSL would work correctly.  Make sure you point secure.yourdomain.com to the same folder as your yourdomain.com.

Everything else should work at that point.